# Is there any way to translate an EER - Model into a Dimensional Model automatically?

Tags: entity-relationship, dimensional-modeling

I've got an EER - Model in MYSQL and would like to have a Dimensional Model from that.

Can I

1. Translate that one-to-one, and
2. Is there any way to create a dimensional model digitally?

EDIT: question 2 means if there is program that is made for that purpose to make  a figure. I assume I simply use office now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, it is not possible. Even if it was technically possible (of course it is always possible to write a program to perform almost any task) the resulting model would be useless.

A dimensional model is designed based on your reporting requirements, not on the structure of any source system you might be importing data from.

I'm not sure what you mean in your 2nd point "*Is there any way to create a dimensional model digitally?*". Everything you do on a computer is "digital" so please could you clarify exactly what you are asking here?